# What is the equivalent to "serverweroptin /detailed" in Windows Server 2019 Server Core?

Tags: windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

I am trying to configure my servers to automatically send detailed error reports. On previous versions of Windows Server (in a Server Core installation), I would run:

```
serverweroptin /detailed
```

However, it seems that serverweroptin is not present on Windows Server 2019 (Server Core installation). What would be the supported, recommended command to put the equivalent configuration in place?

These systems are not joined to a domain and have no graphical user interface, so valid answers must present a cmd.exe command or PowerShell command. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After using Sysinternals Process Monitor to watch what ServerWerOptin.exe does on Windows Server 2012 R2, I was able to observe that it writes two registry values when run with the /detailed switch. On Windows Server 2019, since ServerWerOptin.exe is missing, the following command:

```
ServerWerOptin.exe /detailed
```

Can be approximated by running the following equivalent commands:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v "Disabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Consent" /v "DefaultConsent" /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f
```

---

For those more interested in the /disable switch, the equivalent command is:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v "Disabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---

And for those interested in the /summary switch, the equivalent commands are:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v "Disabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\Consent" /v "DefaultConsent" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```